# Python: Different accuracy in and out of a function

Tags: python

I know there are many questions and articles about floating point precision in Python and in general. But I didn't find the answer to this question.

I am calculating the same statement once by calling a function and second time without it. The value calculated by the function deviates by 0.003 which is not little. How can I get the same precision from the function?

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from math import *

sigma = 0.174


def g(ltv):
    ans = 1 - norm.cdf(0.5 * pow(sigma, 2) - log(ltv) / sigma)
    print(ans)

g(0.7)

ans1 = 1 - (norm.cdf((0.5 * pow(sigma, 2) - log(0.7)) / sigma))
print(ans1)
```

Output:

0.0194617840206

0.016304852863

Comment: Your two calculations are not identical. Closing for simple typo.

Comment: "I am calculating the same statement" - only it's not the same statement. Why not copy-paste the exact same line into both areas rather than retyping it with different grouping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am calculating the same statement

No, you're not. This

```
0.5 * pow(sigma, 2) - log(ltv) / sigma
```

is **not** equivalent to this

```
(0.5 * pow(sigma, 2) - log(0.7)) / sigma
```

The [precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of operators, dude.

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)